# How to save image to local computer using php?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

post data with `imageData=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC`

```
$imgData = $_REQUEST['imageData'];
$data = base64_decode($imgData);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if($im !== false) {
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   imagepng($im, 'test.png');
   imagedestroy($im);
   echo 'Success !!!';
} else {
   echo 'Failer ???';
}
```

How to save image to my computer, not save in website ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
imagepng($im, 'test.png');
```

You are telling `imagepng()` to generate a png file and save it with the name you provided.

If instead you do:

```
imagepng($im);
```

It will generate the PNG image to the output (sending to client).

You basically only need that, and remove the `echo`, you are not supposed to send anything with the image data.

If you want to force download, use:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloadme.png"');
imagepng($im);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to save image to my computer, not save in website ?

Use a header to prompt a download.

```
<?php 
$imgData = $_REQUEST['imageData'];
$data = base64_decode($imgData);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if($im !== false) {
    // set the headers, to trigger a download
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: -1");
    header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"');
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
} else {
    echo 'Failer ???';
}
?>
```